# Jquery - Selecting a number string within a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have tried to do this a few different ways and haven't found something that works without having to repeat the code over and over. 
I am trying to select a a alpha numeric word on a web page. It's repeated several time throughout the page but the numeric part changes. 
.i.e. 
(Figure 1), (Figure 2), (Figure 3) and so on.

I been able to select the figure words but not the numeric number. I started with [Johann Burkard](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) highlight code which works great. But I can't figure out how to get the numeric part to work. I was originally thinking using a regular expression but don't know how to include that into the code.

Here is what I have thus far...

```
var num = 2;

$('div').highlight('(figure' + ' ' + 'num' + ')');
```

and I tried also...

```
$('div').highlight('(figure /^[0-9\b]/)');
```

Any ideas?

This is what works...

```
  $('div').highlight('(figure 1)');
  $('div').highlight('(figure 2)');
  $('div').highlight('(figure 3)');
```

I am trying to simplify it, so I don't have to write one for every item.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex

Comment: Should the first example not be: $('div').highlight('(figure' + ' ' + num + ')');

That is, no quotes around num.

Comment: you have `'num'` in quotes. so the output of that string addition is going to be `'(figure num)'` not `'(figure 2)'`

Comment: Looked at the demo - didn't really answer my question on mixing the string with numbers-

Comment: @GPicazo - I thought the num wouldn't need quotes since its a variable. but it doesn't work with or without the quotes.

Comment: Any chance you could post more code? If not, does it work with:

$('div').highlight('(figure 2)');

Comment: does the plugin even accept regex ? i couldn't find any mention of regex

Comment: @GPicazo - The code is fairly simple. Once you have the js  file linked it should just use the one line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJQRbW

```
<div>(figure 1)</div>
<div>(figure 2)</div>
<div>(figure 3)</div>
<div>(figure 4)</div>
<div>(figure 5)</div>
<div>bla</div>

.highlight { background-color: orange }


var num = 5;
$('div').highlight('(figure ' + num + ')');
```

If yours is not working,  you may want to check the usage requirements - make sure you have referenced jquery, then the highlight plugin, then the posted code.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the .highlight css rule defined since all the plugin does is add the class. The visual highlight is actually handled by the style rule.

Comment: I am looking to highlight the entire line of (figure 1), (figure 2), (figure 3) so on and so on... not just one line.

Comment: Ok, if you know a range, you could try something like (depending on the number of items, it may not be very efficient though):

var min = 1, max = 1000;

for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  $('body').highlight('(figure ' + i + ')');
}

Comment: That worked - Thanks very much. I changed the max to 15 since the numbers don't go to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex as a digit finder:

```
$('#text').html().match(/\-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g)
```

Comment: How would I add that onto the existing code?

var num = $('#text').html().match(/-?\d+(.\d+)?/g);

$('div').highlight('(figure' + ' ' + 'num' + ')');

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the code. But having a glance at it, one possible mistake that could be there is that you have the name of the variable in quotes ('num'). If you wan't to use the value of the variable, you shouldn't include the quotes. 
Try this out :

```
$('div').highlight('(figure' + ' ' + num + ')');
```

Comment: If it doesn't work without the quotes, there must be some other mistake in the code. I am trying to look for it. But definitely quotes shouldn't be there , if you want to use the value of the variable num.

Comment: I am thinking that I didn't setup the variable correctly. the variable needs to be able to accept any number. So when it's plugged in to the main string the code will highlight what ever is there.